# How do I use my Sinatra-powered Ruby application to scrape data to a Heroku PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, sequel

I successfully pushed my Sinatra-powered Ruby app to Heroku.

One of the files I pushed is a Ruby script which scrapes the web and puts data into a PostgreSQL database (that's the non-Sinatra one).

I set up a PostgreSQL add-on for the Heroku app, but I haven't gotten further than that.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I'd edit the scraping script (which uses the Sequel gem) to add the data it scrapes to the Heroku PostgreSQL add-on database.

I took a look [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/import-data-heroku-postgres#from-postgres) on it, but I got stuck on the first step. I'm afraid I don't understand the command prompt syntax they listed.

Furthermore, when I tried to follow their alternate instructions using PGAdmin III, I ran into another problem. The Heroku tutorial says:

> As an alternative, you can also create an a dump file using the PGAdmin GUI tool. To do so, select a database from the Object Browser and click Tools > Backup. Set the filename to data.dump, use the “COMPRESS” format, and (under “Dump Options #1”) choose not to save Privilege or Tablespace.

The problem here is I see no "COMPRESS" format in PGAdmin. Instead, I just save the file "data.dump" as an "All files" type without any formatting.

I'm not sure if this is correct, and if it is, what exactly I need to do next.

Can anyone confirm that I'm on the right path, and if so, what specifically I must do next?

EDIT: For clarification, I'm trying to get my scraping script to add its scraping data to the Heroku app's PostgreSQL database. Right now, it's still written as if it were on my local machine, scraping to my local PostgreSQL database.

Comment: A bit confused, are you wanting to schedule the script to run every so often (e.g. once a day) to scrape the source site and add new data to the db, or you want to run it one time to seed the database? If the former, they have plugins like heroku scheduler. If the latter, have your scraper populate a local db, then you should be able to `heroku db:push` (at least that worked last time I played with Heroku)

Comment: @JoshuaCheek, sorry for the confusion. I guess I am a bit perplexed myself about this. Actually, what I'm trying to do is to actually get the script to scrape to my Heroku app's PostgreSQL database. Right now, I have it written as it was before I pushed it. That is, it scrapes to my local PostgreSQL database.

Comment: So your difficulty is how to give the script access to the PostgreSQL database that Heroku has set up for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/ca49a830723e133cd7c2376d9553c50e6996b129/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb#L156) you can run

```
heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --app your-app-name
```

where "DATABASE" is literally the word "DATABASE". Once you have the credentials, configure your script to access that database.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I ran that from the command prompt, and put the info into Sequel's Postgres paramaters (http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html)